# Identify the UITextField with first responder in my current UIView

Tags: uitableview, first-responder, becomefirstresponder

I have more than 5 text fields in my registration view to get input from the user & the user can choose to edit any of the text field of the available 5.

At any instance in my application, I want to get the `UITextField`(or a reference of the `UITextField`) with is the acting as the current first responder in the registration `UIView`(self.view)

Appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mainly wanted to remove the current active responder in my view. The below code helped me achieve that.

```
 [self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Thanks for Stackover flow again.